# Invalid Field Mapping in DataLoader

Tags: data-loader, tasks, update

DataLoader is not loading the column correctly.

I'm trying to update Task...But I get the error "Id not specified in an update call"

What i have to do in this case?

[image]

Comment: try renaming column B as `WhoId`

Comment: I put WhoId and I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the separator list of my computer and Excel to comma(,)